# Java Thread Interruption in a general sense

Tags: java, multithreading

One of the most suggested ways to pause a thread is to extend the Runnable interface by adding a pause() method:

```
interface RunnablePausable extends Runnable {
    public void pause();
}
```

This never made sense to me since you don't actually want to pause the runnable but the Thread that runs it, in the same way you start/interrupt a Thread, not a Runnable.

---

A more elegant approach: since the interrupt() functionality is well built-in and supported by multiple methods, what if we interrupt() a Thread not just to terminate it, but for a general request instead (like you would interrupt a CPU, in a way)? And then let the Runnable handle this specific request

As an example: interrupt() the thread and, instead of straight up terminating it, handle its request to pause, stop, resume, or do anything else you like.

Not sure if this makes sense.

Something like this:

```
public void run() {
    try {
        //...
    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {     //interrupted
        if (i_wanted_to_pause) {            //manage request
            //wait
        }
        if (i_wanted_to_stop) {
            //return
        }
        if (any_other_request) {
            //handle it
        }
    }
}
```

And:

```
public void run() {
    if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {   //interrupted
        if (request_to_pause) {                     //manage request
            //wait
        }
        if (request_to_stop) {
            //return
        }
        if (any_request) {
            //handle it
        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem is: how to make a specific request to the interrupted thread?

How can I communicate my request to the interrupted thread, as if was meant to stop, pause, or do anything else?

Ideas:

- Subclass InterruptedException into InterruptedExceptionStop and InterruptedExceptionPause (no idea how I can throw them)
- Create a separate object containing the request. Don't know what would be the best way to achieve this without over-complicating things
- Other?

Comment: `One of the most suggested ways to pause a thread is to extend the Runnable interface by adding a pause()` Um, no.  Who is suggesting this?

Comment: `since the interrupt() functionality is well built-in and supported by multiple methods, what if we interrupt() a Thread not just to terminate it, but for a general request` Sorry but also a terrible idea.  The rest of Java and its API assumes that interrupt == terminate.  You really don't want try to do something else with it, it breaks too much stuff.  What is the actual use case for trying to manipulate threads like this?  I feel an [XY Problem here.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @markspace I wanted to pause a Thread. Saw people suggesting to call wait() by checking if property isPaused==true. So I was trying to avoid extending the Runnable interface/Thread class to add the `boolean isPaused` flag. Makes sense? Thank you

Comment: @markspace So came up the idea to use the already existing `interrupted` flag and interruption mechanism to change the normal flow of the Thread and solve different request, including (but not limited to) pausing, resuming, stopping, etc

Comment: `I wanted to pause a Thread.` But *why?* What is your actual use case for this?  Normally pausing is a bad idea, I can't think of a single reason to do it.  (And pausing is different from blocking.)

Comment: There are classes in the java.util.concurrent package that make this easier.  CountDownLatch, Semaphore, CyclicBarrier.  As markspace said, interrupts have a specific purpose already, and you don’t want to undermine that.  There will be times when another thread needs your thread to stop what it’s doing and exit as cleanly as possible; that is precisely what an interrupt is for.  That is why most blocking methods in Java SE immediately throw InterruptedException.

Comment: @markspace, that could be an answer if you'd build on it a bit. The question is, what happens if the interrupt is fired while the thread is deep in 3rd-party library land? What do interrupts mean to a library? What's the policy? In what state does the interrupt leave the library's objects and (God help us) static variables? Some developers probably don't even know how many open-source libraries their project depends on. I've been working (on and off) with Java almost since the very beginning, and I don't recall anybody having much to say about that topic.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Brian Goetz's book *Java Concurrency in Practice* goes into more detail on the interrupt policy of a thread.  My copy is missing atm so I can't quote intelligently, but as VGR points out Java language primitives (like `wait()`) and blocking API methods (file IO for ex) all exit immediately on interrupt, so a thread can shut itself down.  It's the way they're designed and really the only choice a Java programmer has, we're boxed in.  Also per VGR, if you want to control the flow of a thread the `java.util.concurrent` classes are a much better idea.

Comment: @markspace, I pulled my copy of Goetz of the shelf, and wouldn't you know? there was a flag on the page with the heading "Interruption." He says that an interrupt generally means a request for the thread to stop something that it is doing and do some other thing instead. He says that you should never write code that "swallows" an interrupt request, and he says that every thread should have a documented "interruption policy." That plus several pages of pretty good -seeming advice. I just don't know if every developer of every library that my project depends on has taken the advice to heart.

Comment: Yup [java docs on interrupts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html) says `An interrupt is an indication to a thread that it should stop what it is doing and do something else. It's up to the programmer to decide exactly how a thread responds to an interrupt` and then `but it is very common for the thread to terminate` So I assumed that interrupts may be a general way to interact with a thread, it just usually happens that the most common request was a thread termination. AFAIK embedded systems use interrupts to interact with a thread loop,so it does work

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, as @markspace said in the comments, there is no any practical reason to request a thread to do things like pause/resume/etc at any moment(?).

The thread is just the calculation in general meaning. You know, there is the following popular pattern for CPU intensive executions:

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
```

This means `a thread ~= a CPU core`. See a thread as a CPU core here. I believe this is an idiomatic view - a long-living sequential calculation, a conveyor. Do you think there should be a way to `pause` a CPU core by a user? To stop the conveyor by a button stuck to each box on it? I don't think so. So, if you want to prevent CPU from the calculation, just don't ask it to do the calculation. A classical example - Job/Task Queue baked with a thread and a BlockingQueue. You split your calculation into several jobs to consume them to the queue. If you don't consume new ones (optionally clear the queue), your thread is 'paused' naturally on `take()`. The same for IO, until you are OK to burn CPU with completely non-blocking solutions. With your code, you also have to take care about 3rd party things/objects you use in your run() to don't get them accidentally broken after the interruption, since it's true that "`interruption == termination`" is a commonplace semantically.

Another possible argument against the approach is mostly an architectural one. `Runnable`, `Callable` are examples of the IoC (Inversion of Control) pattern. But we introduce a control/execution management method into them, and this smells IMO.

If you had explained what was the specific problem you were trying to address, we would suggest a more suitable, more idiomatic than `RunnablePausable` approach.

2. Now, why do I like the question. It's inspiring to me when developers think about their things so deeply. It's nice when they invent something, even if these are their own homebrewed Continuations and Schedulers:) It may be an instructive game/experiment.